# WHM My website is not working wen using the default URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

How do I fix this in `WHM`/`CPANEL`?

The website is working with this link. 
`http://68.171.210.68/~decongestmanila/` [here](http://68.171.210.68/~decongestmanila/)

But now without those numbers before the URL. 
`https://www.decongestmetromanila.com/` [here](https://www.decongestmetromanila.com/)

The later returns

[image]

Comment: Please check this link:- http://crybit.com/stop-accessing-with-ip-username/

Comment: @A-2-A Hi, thanks. I followed the instruction but I cant see the Home >> Security Center >> Apache mod_userdir Tweak. There is no `Security Center` link on the home dashboard? Why is that?